# How to connect two different computers on different networks with socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

I've learnt to set up a client and a server in the same machine.
But is there a way to send and receive data over the internet with sockets?

Comment: Well, yes, you can.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a socket-based connection work over internet you will have to:

- not bind to `127.0.0.1` but to an IP available on an network interface

You can check your local interfaces using the command `ip address` or `ifconfig` on linux and `ipconfig` on windows. Find the interface that corresponds to your internet connection. That IP (for example `192.168.0.101`) is what you want

- make sure there are no firewalls (your computer, your router, ISP, ...) blocking the port you bind to

Your computer's firewall is up to you to configure. Port-forwarding on an router usually automatically creates the required firewall rules.

Some ISPs block all incoming connections. If this is the case you will either have to talk with the ISP or use some sort of VPN connection from within your network.

- if you're behind a router/NAT you will have to add port-forwarding from the router IP to your server's IP

You will have to find the IP address of the router. Look at your computers default gateway/route. Check the internet for instructions for a specific model.

Comment: Sorry but can you brief the steps?
I can take care of firewall. But I don't know which IP I should use.Do I need a server?

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan I added some details to the answer, ask if you want to know more

Comment: Will this code work when all settings are right?
Server - http://pastebin.com/eg5N6yC3 
Client - http://pastebin.com/feWYMwQw
My IP is 192.168.2.1

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan That will work inside your LAN. If you want it to work over internet google for "my wan ip" and enter that in the client.

Comment: Error 10049: The requested address is not valid in it's context. :/ Also, one doubt. I should use my public IP address for both server and client right?

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan You listen on your local/private address. You connect to your public address (router). The router then connects to your local address (port forwarding)

Comment: If I listen to "192.168.2.1" (My private IP) this error occurs - The requested address is not valid in its context
If I listen to socket.gethostname() no error occurs, but the program doesn't seem to work. ie the message doesn't get printed. :(
Thanks a lot! You've been helping me all along! :)
Images for reference - http://s1368.photobucket.com/user/Subramanian7/library/Python%20sockets
Also, I just found out an issue. The client doesn't show an error when it's run even if the server program isn't running. :/

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan Please post the results of `ipconfig` on windows command line

Comment: http://i1368.photobucket.com/albums/ag180/Subramanian7/Capture1_zps38azadzp.png

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan Your local IP is `192.168.2.3`. `.2.1` is your router's

Comment: Is this correct? http://i1368.photobucket.com/albums/ag180/Subramanian7/Untitled_zps2uyl0gae.png
If not, tell me where I'm wrong. If its correct, nothing is happening :/ and as I told earlier, the client program doesn't throw an error if its executed when the server isn't running.

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan Do you have port forwarding on your router?

Comment: I don't know. How should I check it? Ask the ISP?

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan I think that is a no. You need to login to your router (unless blocked by ISP). Put the `192.168.2.1`IP in you browser and try some default credentials. Port forward `port 12345` to `192.168.2.3:12345`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37295364/5211920